# Selenium unable to login with webdriver

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver

How are sites protected from being log in by Selenium web driver?

At the same time you can enter the log in form manually and all other part of selenium code will work, how is that achieved?

Is it possible to log in into such site by Selenium web driver?

```
<!-- login form -->
<form action="login.php?do=login" method="post" onsubmit="md5hash(vb_login_password, vb_login_md5password, vb_login_md5password_utf, 0)">
<script type="text/javascript" src="clientscript/vbulletin_md5.js?v=387"></script>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3" border="0">
<tr>
<td class="smallfont" style="white-space: nowrap;"><label for="navbar_username">Имя</label></td>
<td><input type="text" class="bginput" style="font-size: 11px" name="vb_login_username" id="navbar_username" size="10" accesskey="u" tabindex="101" value="Имя" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Имя') this.value = '';" /></td>
<td class="smallfont" nowrap="nowrap"><label for="cb_cookieuser_navbar"><input type="checkbox" name="cookieuser" value="1" tabindex="103" id="cb_cookieuser_navbar" accesskey="c" />Запомнить?</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="smallfont"><label for="navbar_password">Пароль</label></td>
<td><input type="password" class="bginput" style="font-size: 11px" name="vb_login_password" id="navbar_password" size="10" tabindex="102" /></td>
<td><input type="submit" class="button" value="Вход" tabindex="104" title="Введите ваше имя пользователя и пароль, чтобы войти, или нажмите кнопку 'Регистрация', чтобы зарегистрироваться." accesskey="s" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="s" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="securitytoken" value="1494435076-6acf057fb2e17e28bd5679c57501a85f896b4310" />
<input type="hidden" name="do" value="login" />
<input type="hidden" name="vb_login_md5password" />
<input type="hidden" name="vb_login_md5password_utf" />
</form>
<!-- / login form -->
```

Comment: It is possible that you are not actually able to log in because you are not on the right page, or you are not selecting the correct elements for your input and submission. Please show some code as an example.

Comment: I'm not able to understand the question? Sites are not protected from being log in by Selenium.

Comment: @ElementCR what could you say about that login form?

Comment: @bad_deadpool than form is poosible to log in manualy but not with selenium

Comment: What error it gives when you try with Selenium code?

Comment: @bad_deadpool the site says that wrong username and password

Comment: @thinker I went ahead and wrote up a small excerpt that is tailored to the page you put up after the edit. I think it is a decent place to start. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can log in with Selenium in two ways:

1. Via filling out a form on the login page. This involves finding username and password elements and inputting information for a test user you have created in a test database.
2. Login on the backend of your system programatically rather than using the UI. This will still require a username and password, should just work in a test environment, and the syntax depends upon what kind of authentication module you are using.

Answer (score 1):

---

> How are sites protected from being log in by Selenium web driver?

I haven't seen any site that can differentiate between human and Selenium webdriver accessing the webpage. There may be some, I am not sure. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver).

However, it is difficult to automate tasks for site for which `id, classname, name` of html tags changes on each reload. [Google plus](https://plus.google.com/) is one such example, there are many. For sites like [Bet365](https://www.bet365.com/) it is difficult to automate tasks because there are real time reloads.

To differentiate between bot and humans CAPTCHA is used by websites.

---

> At the same time you can enter the log in form manualy and all other part of selenium code will work, how is that achived?

Yes, it can be achieved. You can make your program wait for a duration and enter your information (eg: username, password). Then you can perform operations like click or select using your script. *But your browser should be opened using Webdriver.*

To make your program wait you can use `Thread.sleep(int)`, but you can go for [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40254276/need-to-write-the-selenium-code-without-the-thread-sleep) for better results.

Here the tough job will be deciding the wait time, because every human won't have same speed for entering values.

---

*As suggested by [ElementCR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2947055/elementcr), `sendkeys("value")` is better than manual input.*

Answer (score 0):

After looking for some examples I found this reference.
[How to valid a login page using Java and Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22614290/how-to-valid-a-login-page-using-java-and-selenium-webdriver)

Be sure to switch up the findElement(By.(Identifier)).

Not sure if this will provide immediate results, but this is where I would start.

Good luck.

```
@Before
public void setup() throws MalformedURLException, UnknownHostException{
driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
driver.get(System.getProperty("login.url"));
}

@Test
public void login(){
driver.findElement(By.name("vb_login_username")).sendKeys("login");
driver.findElement(By.name("vb_login_password")).sendKeys("password");     
driver.findElement(By.type("submit")).click();
}
```

Comment: I cannot at the moment, but later in the day I can give it a shot. Do you have valid test cases that I can use? If you send me a private message I can see what is possible.